# Socket: Incorrect request-response through a socket using readUTF() and writeUTF()

Tags: java, sockets

There's a simple console application that consists of server side and client side. Server side listens to some port, when client connects server starts to send questions in menu-like style. For example:

> 1. Print exist data
> 2. Add new data
> 3. Edit exist data
> 4. Remove exist data

Client in its turn sends menu number and waits for server's reaction. After each command server must send menu list again.

As you will see from example below, Client connects to the Server and reads its menu, then starts to interact with it. But this interaction isn't as smooth as it expected. Sometimes data is sent by pieces. Each client response should be followed by Enter pressed twice in order to get response from Server.

Here is ready to compile example of the problem I ran at in my app:

Server (one Java project):

```
public class TestServer {
    private static List<String> example;
    static {
        example = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            example.add("Data#" + i);
        }
    }

    private static DataInputStream in;
    private static DataOutputStream out;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(30000);
        System.out.println("*** Waiting for a client...");

        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("*** Client connected!\n");

        in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        while (true) {
            showUserMenu();

            String clientMessage = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Client made a choice: " + clientMessage);

            try {
                int answerChoice = Integer.parseInt(clientMessage);
                analyzeSelection(answerChoice);
                System.out.println("Waiting for client menu choice...\n");
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    }

    private static void analyzeSelection(int answerChoice) {
        try {
            switch(answerChoice) {
                case 1:
                    printExistData();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //2. Add data
                    createNewData();
                    out.writeUTF("New data added!");
                    out.flush();
                    break;
                default:
                    out.writeUTF("There is no such menu item. Please enter correct menu number");
                    out.flush();
                    break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void createNewData() throws IOException {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        out.writeUTF("Do you want to set change name? (y/n)");
        out.flush();
        if(isYes()) {
            out.writeUTF("Enter data name: ");
            out.flush();
            builder.append(in.readUTF());
        }
        out.writeUTF("Do you want to set data value? (y/n)");
        if(isYes()) {
            out.writeUTF("Enter data value: ");
            out.flush();
            builder.append(in.readUTF());
        }
        example.add(builder.toString());
    }

    private static boolean isYes() throws IOException {
        return in.readUTF().toLowerCase().equals("y");
    }

    private static void printExistData() throws IOException {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(String s : example) {
            builder.append("- ").append(s).append("\n");
        }
        out.writeUTF(builder.toString());
        out.flush();
    }

    private static void showUserMenu() throws IOException {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("1. Print exist data\n").append("2. Add new data\n")
               .append("*** Type menu number and press Enter.");
        out.writeUTF(builder.toString());
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Client (another Java project):

```
public class TestClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
        System.out.println("*** Ready to connect to 127.0.0.1:30000");

        Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, 30000);
        System.out.println("*** Connection established!");

        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        //Read client input from keyboard
        BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        while(true) {
            String serverResponse = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println(serverResponse);

            String clientResponse = keyboard.readLine();
            out.writeUTF(clientResponse);
            out.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the overall output of communication between client and server:

```
[SERVER]*** Waiting for a client...
[CLIENT]*** Ready to connect to 127.0.0.1:30000
[CLIENT]*** Connection established!
[SERVER]*** Client connected!
[CLIENT]1. Print exist data
2. Add new data
*** Type menu number and press Enter.
[CLIENT]1
[SERVER]Client made a choice: 1
[CLIENT]- Data#0
- Data#1
- Data#2
- Data#3
- Data#4
[SERVER]Waiting for client menu choice...
[CLIENT] //Press Enter because no menu was printed
[SERVER]Client made a choice: 
[SERVER]For input string: "" //NumberFormatException (NFE)
[CLIENT]1. Print exist data
2. Add new data
*** Type menu number and press Enter.
[CLIENT]2
[SERVER]Client made a choice: 2
[CLIENT]1. Print exist data
2. Add new data
*** Type menu number and press Enter.
[CLIENT]2
[CLIENT]Do you want to set change name? (y/n)
[CLIENT]y
[CLIENT]Do you want to set data value? (y/n)
[CLIENT]y
[CLIENT]Enter data value:
[SERVER]Waiting for client menu choice...
[CLIENT]123
[SERVER]Client made a choice: 123
[SERVER]Waiting for client menu choice...
[CLIENT]New data added!
[CLIENT] //Press Enter because no menu was printed
[SERVER]Client made a choice: 
[SERVER]For input string: "" //NFE
...
```

I see that there is some sort of sync problem. But I cannot understand why it happens.

What is wrong in this communication schema? What is usual way to make client-server communication be more consistent?

Comment: You haven't really described the symptoms very clearly. It would help if you'd show a short but *complete* pair of programs, and a sample session which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I edited the topic. Added ready to compile example with client-server communication output that shows workflow issue.

Comment: It's really unclear what the actual issue is here. At what point is this not what you expected? Were you expecting the menu to be shown after the data? If so, bear in mind that you've called `writeUTF` with the data, so the client thinks *that* is a prompt...

Comment: @JonSkeet, I expect that after the result for client input is sent, new "while" iteration takes place and menu is sent strict after result. So the possible solution is to send "menu" in a stream with result?

Comment: Well if you're wanting to send it in one message, you need to make sure you only call `writeUTF` once (per interaction). So for example your `analyzeSelection` method could return the string to write, and you could then append the menu onto that and call `writeUTF` once. Or you could change your protocol to have some string which basically means "I want input now".

Comment: @JonSkeet, I just started to work with sockets, so I had some misunderstanding. Now it is clear for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your streams should not be static, and they should not even be members of the server class. They should be non-static members of the `Runnable` class that you should instantiate when you create the new Thread that you should create to handle each connection.

Comment: If you are talking about DataInput/OutputStream, so they are static in this "ready to compile" example. But in my real app they are the part of a server class, hm. Btw, Client and Server from the example - are different Java projects.

Comment: In that case you should stop wasting everybody's time and post the actual code.

Comment: in actual code the issue it the same. One should press Enter twice after server response in order to get menu or whatever else.

Comment: Or whatever. If you post code you will get comments on it. This is mine. If it isn't the real code whose problem is that?

Comment: in fact it is real code (I have the same workflow in "full app"), besides it shorted a little and put in `main` (that's why streams are static).